# jqGrid: Number format with comma as decimal point

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using the 'number' type for entering floating point numbers into a jqGrid grid.
I am able to format the floats for rendering witha comma (we use a comman in Europe
as decimal seperator). However the input fields (edit form or inline) still assume that
that entered floating point numbers use a dot and not a comma.

```
formatoptions: {decimalSeperator : ','}
```

seems to influcence the rendering but not the validation of the input data.

Any reasonable options here?

Comment: I think, The spelling of the word "seperator" is not correct. Modify spelling as "separator"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own custom formmaters.

[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)

The guide explains it well. You must create a formmater and an unformmater for editing.

Create a formatting function like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
    ...
       colModel: [ 
          ... 
          {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true, formatter:numFormat, unformat:numUnformat},
          ...
       ]
    ...
    });

    function numFormat( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
        return cellvalue.replace(".",",");
    }

    function numUnformat( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
        return cellvalue.replace(",",".");
    }
</script>
```

You can also append $ or other formatting in these functions.

Comment: Nota Bene: Thousand separator converter is a space for continentals when anglo-saxons use ","

Comment: That would not answer the question given by the owner of the question.

Comment: That is why it is a comment ; if you keep the english thousand's separator, you will get a nonsense for any number notation, 

    e.g.  12,345,678.9 -> 12,345,678,9 

instead of the correct (and owner requested) 

    12345678,9